# Double dual space of a C* algebra A

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

We know that $A$ embeds into $A$** (the  double dual space of  $A$ ). Is the following true? If $\Psi$ is in $A$** and weak* continuous, is there  an element $a \in A$ such that   $ \Psi$ is the evaluation functional at $a$? That is to say, $\Psi(f)=f(a)$ for any $ f \in A^{*}$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has nothing to do with operator algebras as it is well-known that if $B$ is a linear topological space (local convexity and Hausdorff-ness hypothesis included), the topological dual of $B^{\ast}$ endowed with the wk*-topology is $B$ itself, that is, every wk*-continuous functional on $B^{\ast}$ is an evaluation functional. For the proof, see for example the first section of chapter V in J. B. Conway's Functional Analysis textbook.

Regards,
G. Rodrigues